# Can I install OS X on a failing SSD?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, install

I have a failing SSD in my Mid-2009 MacBook Pro (5,4) that I'd like to install OS X on. It's only temporary because I'll be ordering a new SSD in a couple of weeks.

The OS X installer rightly alerts me that the drive is failing so I should replace it - but I'm wondering if there's any way to get around this alert and install it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer much advice about the SSD in question given the very limited information you've shared about it.

However, I suggest you try installing OS X onto a USB key (preferably a fast USB 3 one) or SD Card (slower; don't recommend). It'll make migrating your files to your new SSD easier. Just be careful of the protruding hardware!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Apologies for not saying much about the SSD, it's a Kingston ssdNOW 200 120GB. I installed OS X to a 32GB flash drive but can't boot to it - I've double checked and it's GUID partitioned too - that's probably a different question all together though?

Comment: Any sort of diagnostics I'd try running on the drive would require an installation of OS X anyway, so I would suggest you address imaging the USB drive to boot OS X as its own question to tackle first.